# Django placeholder areas

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Im new to Django CMS but I have a query I'm hoping will be a very simple one to answer.

I have a site I'm developing at the minute. I have a block in place for a specific template that allows the client to add PDFs as plugin files in the admin area.

The code at the minute is thus:

```
<div class="highlighter">
    <h3>Application forms</h3>
    {% block page_downloads_area %}{% placeholder "Application Forms" %}{% endblock %}
</div>
```

What I would like to do is add a condition to this that says if their is no content then show no HTML, if their is content then show the HTML, something like this:

```
{% if not page_downloads_area %}
    <p>We currently have no vacancies</p>
    {% else %}
    <div class="highlighter">
    <h3>Application forms</h3>
    {% block page_downloads_area %}{% placeholder "Application Forms" %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Please excuse the poor use of condition if so, as mentioned I'm new to this but I'm hoping this gives the idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: What are the actual results of that code ?, does it show any error or does it show nothing at all ?

Comment: in this instance, the line:
    <p>We currently have no vacancies</p>
is visible and the block element isn't available in the admin. Perhaps blocks are not allowed inside conditionals?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer to this query and it is as follows:

```
<div class="highlighter">
    <h3>Application forms</h3>
    {% block page_downloads_area %}
    {% placeholder "Application Forms” or %}
    <p>We currently have no vacancies</p>
    {% endplaceholder %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
```

It turns out that blocks are not allowed in conditionals so if we give it a variant as such then if their isn't content it displays a note, if their is it displays the content. Tidy little workaround.